# SELECT returning wrong information

Tags: php, mysqli

Alright so, I made this little account check using simple SQL & PHP but it seems to return false instead of true if account exists.

```
public function ifExists($name) {
    $handler = new sql();
    $sql = $handler->connect();
    $sql->real_escape_string($name);

    $result = $sql->query("SELECT ime FROM users WHERE ime='".$name."'");

    if($result == false) { 
        if($result->num_rows != 0) {
            $echo = 'account exists';
            return true;
        }
        else { 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And now here is the check

```
if($result->num_rows != 0) {
     $echo = 'account exists';
     return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

There is a row with ime='toma' in the sql

Comment: Your function does not have a return value for all possible code paths.

Comment: Ahhh yeah, I should set it to return false; I suppose (as a default return). Thanks lad!

Comment: Using string interpolation in queries could lead to SQL injection attacks, and is a bad habit. Have a look at prepared statements: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result == false)
```

`query()` only returns `false` on a syntax error. Also, this is backwards. You should only want to run the code if it's **not** `false`. Drop that `if` block out and it should work

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds